# Jquery Mobile page on Android loses definition after transition

Tags: android, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a website built with Jquery Mobile v1.3.2.
After a transition, some images and texts loose definition, like the image attached.
It doesn't happen on Iphone or Desktop, only on Android.

[image: broken style]

Have anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks in advance!